# Segmentation fault in C while iterating through array

Tags: c, tree, segmentation-fault

I am trying to mimic a basic encryption algorithm. I try to read the encrypted data file and look for each corresponding value in a JRB tree (simple key-value pair in my case) which is basically filled from the ".key" file and then write it to another file.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fields.h"
#include <cJSON.h>
#include "jrb.h"

void decrypt();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
decrypt();
return 0;
}

void decrypt()
{
IS is_input;
FILE *fp;
int i, j;
char *buffer = 0;
char *str = 0;
long length;
FILE *f = fopen ("data/.key", "rb");
cJSON *json;
JRB b, tmp;
b = make_jrb();
tmp = make_jrb();
is_input = new_inputstruct("data/encrypted");

if (is_input == NULL) {
    perror("Error: ");
    exit(1);
}

fp = fopen("data/decrypted.txt", "w+");
if (fp < 0) { perror("Error: "); exit(1); }

if (f)
{
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (f);
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc (length);
    if (buffer)
    {
    fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
    }
    fclose (f);
}

if (buffer)
{
    json = cJSON_Parse(buffer);
    cJSON *current_element = NULL;
    char *current_key = NULL;

    cJSON_ArrayForEach(current_element, json)
    {
        current_key = current_element->string;
        if (current_key != NULL)
        {
            (void) jrb_insert_str(b, strdup(current_element->valuestring), new_jval_v(current_key));
        }
    }
    while(get_line(is_input) >= 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < is_input->NF; i++) {
        str = is_input->fields[i];

        tmp = jrb_find_str(b, "10001011"); // This works but when I use "str" here instead of "10001011", I get a segmentation fault.
        // tmp = jrb_find_str(b, str);
        fprintf(fp, "%s ", tmp->val.s);
    }
    }
}

jettison_inputstruct(is_input);
fclose(fp);
return;
}
```

The .key file is like this:

```
  {
    "hi": "0",
    "merhaba": "10",
    "hallo": "11"
  }
```

After running the program with printf I get a Segmentation fault after printing it is data like this:
0 10 11Segmentation fault (core dumped)

But if I try to use fprintf to write it into another file I directly get the Segmentation fault error.
I tried to debug and I see that the tmp value is null but how can it be null?

About JRB: [http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~jplank/plank/classes/cs360/360/notes/JRB/index.html](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/%7Ejplank/plank/classes/cs360/360/notes/JRB/index.html)

**Input struct:**

```
    const char *name;         /* File name */
    FILE *f;                  /* File descriptor */
    int line;                 /* Line number */
    char text1[MAXLEN];       /* The line */
    char text2[MAXLEN];       /* Working -- contains fields */
    int NF;                   /* Number of fields */
    char *fields[MAXFIELDS];  /* Pointers to fields */
    int file;                 /* 1 for file, 0 for popen */
```

Comment: *I have no clue*. Use a debugger to get you some clues. At a minimum it will instantly give you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault.

Comment: @kaylum I found that the tmp variable is null but why?

Comment: I suspect a missing _null character_  is the issue.  `buffer` does not point to a _string_.